# Read cookie from Javascript

Tags: javascript

On a site which is hosted on *.x.com, I am loading a javascript (say javascriptY) from *.y.com. I have some cookie "name=value" stored on *.y.com (some user might have visited *.y.com earlier) and I want to read "name" cookie from the javascriptY which is loaded on *.x.com.

Is there a way to read cookie of *.y.com from javascriptY, which is loaded on *.x.com?

Comment: Before asking a question first read how to ask question and format your question properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a cookie from a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318866/reading-a-cookie-from-a-different-domain)

Comment: Thanks Pablo for the reference. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> ## It is not possible to read a cookie set under a different domain

Because cookies are limited by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), which states that they are specific to the root  of the HTML document they are defined in.

**Cross-domain cookies:**
Have a look at the answer for this question, about [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) for alternative methods of sharing cookies between domains.

Comment: Thanks Lissy, I will have a look.