# Reactivesearch proxylike backend with cookie authentication

Tags: reactivesearch

I have a spring backend which i'm accessing my Elastic search cluster through by a proxylike endpoint. The request has to be authorized with a cookie.

I'm currently using searchkit with supports authenticating requests through the `withCredentials` flag. Is there a similar option for reactivesearch or is there any other solution for authorizing the request with a cookie?

I could add: the backend exposes a swagger client which runs on a different domain than my frontend client. This client "owns" the cookie and thus i cannot read the cookie from my frontend client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so it turns out, Reactivesearch uses fetch and fetch wants `credentials: 'include'` for cookie authentication. This may not be placed in the headers that Reactivesearch supplies and must be placed on the root object for the request.

It's possible to do this by implementing `beforeSend` on ReactiveBase.

```
const Base = ({ children }) => {
  const onBeforeSend = props => {
    return {
      ...props,
      credentials: 'include',
    }
  }

  return (
    <ReactiveBase
      app="app-name"
      url="url"
      beforeSend={onBeforeSend}
    >
      {children}
    </ReactiveBase>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `headers` prop in `ReactiveBase` to pass custom headers along with the requests. [Link](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html#props) to docs. Since there is no `withCredentials` you could read the cookies and set in custom headers to verify the requests at the proxy middleware.

```
<ReactiveBase
  ...
  headers={{
      customheader: 'abcxyz'
  }}
>
    <Component1 .. />
    <Component2 .. />
</ReactiveBase>
```

[Here](https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-server/blob/master/index.js) is a sample proxy server but its in NodeJS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've seen the section about the custom headers and played around with it with no progress. The problem with reading the cookie is that my backend exposes a swagger client which i use and runs on another domain than my frontend client - thus unables reading the cookie from the frontend client.

Comment: You could perhaps use `document.cookie` to read the cookies and send via `headers` prop and then set these at the proxy server.

Comment: It's not possible to read cookies housed on a different domain [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318866/reading-a-cookie-from-a-different-domain)

Comment: Right, seems like this has to be added at the library level, created an issue here https://github.com/appbaseio/appbase-js/issues/42 :)

Comment: I might have found a solution to this. will await with answering my question till i can confirm it works. So far the solution is to hijack on the beforeSend prop and return credentials: 'include' on root level of the request